# How can we manage azure git and build pipeline better?

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines

We have been using azure pipeline and Azure Git for a while, this is our process.

- Every sprint we create a sprint branch based from the Master branch
- For each story, we create a story branch based from the sprint branch
- After PR, the story branch will be rebased on the the sprint branch
- After sprint finish, the sprint branch will be rebased on to the Master branch

Turned out that it is quite difficult to remember to rebase onto the Master branch after sprint finish.
Also we need to change the build pipeline to use the new sprint branch for every sprint.

This really becomes a burden for us and there were some cases we just forgot to merge things back to Master. We have several repositories and it does make the process even worse.

How you guys handle this?

Is it possible to automatically rebase to master branch (so always ignore conflicts)  after sprint finish?

For azure build pipeline, is it possible to apply some rule so we don't have to keep on changing the build source for every sprint?

Comment: hi, I am not sure. Ideally It is not somthing we want to go for. If azure pipeline can give us more tools, I think it will be better

Comment: Did you host your repo in Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git#deploy-with-azure-pipelines-builds) or in Azure DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT repo in azure

Answer (score 0):

> How you guys handle this?

We do ca the same but without any sprint branch.

On one project we merge the story branch into master once the story is finished.

On another project we have a "dev" branch in addition to master.
So stories are rebased into dev once they are finished, and then dev is merged into master when we are ready for a release, which triggers UAT and production pipelines.

> Is it possible to automatically rebase to master branch (so always ignore conflicts) after sprint finish?

You might be able to do this with a [scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

But I think an easier solution is having a long-lived dev branch, rather than short-lived sprint branches. I.e. rebase stories into dev once the story is finished, and then merge dev into master at the end of the sprint.
It doesn't fix forgetting to merge to master, but it would ensure work isn't lost in a forgotten branch.

> For azure build pipeline, is it possible to apply some rule so we don't have to keep on changing the build source for every sprint?

If all the sprint branches are names similarily,
you could use a trigger that matches all of them.

I.e. something like this in the `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
trigger: sprint/*
```

More [info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) including how to do the same in the classic UI, if you're not using YAML.